# How do I change the default password for an OpenMQ broker running as LOCAL in Glassfish 3.1.1?

Tags: glassfish, openmq

I'm trying to change the default password for the admin user in a OpenMQ broker instance running as LOCAL in a Glassfish cluster. I tried logging in to the server locally and using the imqusermgr tool but that didn't work. I'm guessing I have to use some 
asadmin set command but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your custom password for your broker.

1. Go to **MessageQueue5.0/etc/mq** directory. Here you will find **passfile.sample** file.
2. Read this file. There are a lot of administration properties you can set. Admin password in one of it(**imq.imqcmd.password**).
3. After setting this you have to set following properties in brokers **config.properties** file (a.**imq.passfile.enabled=true** b.**imq.passfile.dirpath=  directory of the file** and c. **imq.passfile.name=name of the passfile**)
4. You will find this config.properties file in **MessageQueue5.0/var/mq/instances/imqbroker/props** folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `asadmin set` command after using the `imqusermgr` tool:

```bash
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.jms-service.jms-host.default_JMS_host.admin-password="password"
```